# Error when adding entry to a List of Maps

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I'm a little new to generics in Java. I ran into the following situation and I dont understand why the code is not working.

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>> listEntries = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> entry = new HashMap<String,String>();
smsListEntry.put("1", "abc");
smsListEntry.put("2", "xyz");
listEntries.add(entry);
```

It gives me a compile time error that says something like :

> The method `add(capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,String>)` in the type `List<capture#1-of ? extends Map<String,String>>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Map<String,String>`)

Comment: I formatted the code snippets in the quoted error message. '<' and '>' are interpreted as markup by default, unless you format them as code (by putting them between backticks (`) or indenting the text by 4 spaces).

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
List<Map<String, String>> listEntries = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
            Map<String,String> entry = new HashMap<String,String>();
            entry.put("1", "abc");
            entry.put("2", "xyz");
            listEntries.add(entry);
            System.out.println(listEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine if you changed

```
Map<String,String> entry = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

to

```
Map<String,String> entry = new TreeMap<String,String>();
```

Now you've added a `TreeMap` to your `ArrayList` of `HashMap`.

Ditch the wildcards, and use the generic argument you actually want.

```
List<Map<String, String>> listEntries = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
```

Update: To make this more explicit, image taking a reference to the `ArrayList` with the original generics.

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> orig = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<? extends Map<String, String>> listEntries = orig;
listEntries.add(new TreeMap<>()); // Shouldn't work!
HashMap<String,String> treeMap = orig.get(0); // Oops!
```

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I'm a bit confused here.`List<? extends Map<String, String>> listEntries = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>()`. This statement means that I want a list of objects that can be anything that extend map.It could be a HashMap or a TreeMap or just a Map. If that is the case, then the line - `listEntries.add(entry);
` must work because entry is a Map (though implemented as HashMap). Could you tell me where my understanding is messed up?

Comment: @Poornima Prakash What you've actually created is an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`. You could still have a reference to that object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `List<? extends Map<...>` means “I have a list restricted to contain some type which extends `Map`, but I don't know the exact type”. Now suppose the exact type is in fact `TreeMap`: it makes sense that you cannot put an `HashMap` into this list.

Generally speaking, if you have some `Type<E>` and you declare `Type<? extends X> var`, you will never be allowed to call any method on `var` that takes an `E` as parameter because the compiler cannot determine what the `?` allows (maybe `X` but maybe only some subtype of `X`). That's why you cannot call `add` here.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>> listEntries = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

You should write that as

```
List<Map<String, String>> listEntries = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
```

You should define the list type by using the entries Interface.

And then use it like:

```
Map<String,String> entry = new HashMap<String,String>();
entry.put("1", "abc");
entry.put("2", "xyz");
listEntries.add(entry);
listEntries.add(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>()); // if you want you can use different implementations of Map
```

Comment: I tried that first. It gives a compile time error again saying: `codeType mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> to List<Map<String,String>>`

Comment: That doesn't compile, because a `List<HashMap<String,String>>` is **not** a `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: Should be `new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>`

Comment: That works. But why is that so ? Isn't it always possible to assign a HashMap variable to a Map variable.

Comment: My bad, copy-pasted from OP and missed that part.

Comment: That kinda forces me to use "Map". What if I want to use a different implementation of Map here? Is that not possible?

Comment: A different implementation of `Map` will still implement the interface `Map`, so you just have to instantiate a different object and add it to the list. Makes no difference to the collection.